# Program.cs Compiler Error CS0311 With line builder.Services.AddScoped<IModelBuilder<T>, AdminModelBuilder>(); in vs 2022 .netcore 6

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-6.0

In visual studio .netcore 6, my Program.cs file I want to register a builder class to use in my application.  The line

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<IModelBuilder<T>, AdminModelBuilder>();
```

gives me a Compiler Error

Error   CS0311  The type 'WorkbenchAPI.Builders.AdminModelBuilder' cannot be used as type parameter 'TImplementation' in the generic type or method 'ServiceCollectionServiceExtensions.AddScoped<TService, TImplementation>(IServiceCollection)'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'WorkbenchAPI.Builders.AdminModelBuilder' to 'WorkbenchAPI.Builders.IModelBuilder'.
and
Error   CS0311  The type 'WorkbenchAPI.Builders.AdminModelBuilder' cannot be used as type parameter 'TImplementation' in the generic type or method 'ServiceCollectionServiceExtensions.AddScoped<TService, TImplementation>(IServiceCollection)'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'WorkbenchAPI.Builders.AdminModelBuilder' to 'WorkbenchAPI.Builders.IModelBuilder'.

and also
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'T' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

This code did work fine in vs 2015.net.

How can I get this to compile so I can use it in my application. Below is the IModelBuilder.cs interface and AdminModelBuilder.cs file that uses the interface and finally the model AdminModel.cs.

IModelBuilder.cs

```
    namespace MyApplication.Builders
        {
            public interface IModelBuilder<T>
            {
                IModelBuilder<T> WithId(int id);
                IModelBuilder<T> WithModel(T model);
                T Build();
            }
        }
```

AdminModelBuilder.cs

```
    namespace MyApplication.Builders
    {
        public class AdminModelBuilder : IModelBuilder<AdminModel>
        {

            public AdminModelBuilder()
            {
           .
       .    
       .
           }

        public IModelBuilder<AdminModel> WithId(int id)
        {
           .
       .    
       .
        }

        public IModelBuilder<AdminModel> WithModel(AdminModel model)
        {
           .
       .    
       .
        }

        public AdminModel Build()
        {
           .
       .    
       .

        }
       }
   }
```

```
AdminModel.cs
    namespace MyApplication.Data.ViewModels
    {
    public class AdminModel
    {
        public int param1 { get; set; }
        public int param2 { get; set; }
        public int param3 { get; set; }
    }
   }
```

This did work with .net vs 2015, I tried replacing the T with AmdinModel and got same error.

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<IModelBuilder<AdminModel>, AdminModelBuilder>();
```

Comment: It is somewhat hard to believe that `builder.Services.AddScoped<IModelBuilder<AdminModel>, AdminModelBuilder>;` compiled in any version of C#. Is your question "why C# 6 did allow 'method group' to be used without call" ? (clearly you know how to call a method... so I don't expect you to question current error)

Comment: Aren't you missing the parenthesis - `builder.Services.AddScoped<IModelBuilder<AdminModel>, AdminModelBuilder>();`?

Comment: Yes I realized I removed them and added "()" back now get CS0246 and CS0311 So I updated question.

Comment: Could you recompile and show the EXACT error you got with builder.Services.AddScoped<IModelBuilder<AdminModel>, AdminModelBuilder>();

Comment: I recompiled with builder.Services.AddScoped<IModelBuilder<AdminModel>, AdminModelBuilder>(); and it compiled, must have not try compiled change because of the confusion over the miss "()" Thanks it compiles fine now

Answer (score 1):

You have to register using the actual type `IModelBuilder<AdminModel>`, not the generic variant `IModelBuilder<T>`.

Instead of

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<IModelBuilder<T>, AdminModelBuilder>();
```

please use

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<IModelBuilder<AdminModel>, AdminModelBuilder>();
```